# webpack-dev-server (devServer) doesn't receive json data (payload) from axios | req.query & req.params are empty

Tags: json, webpack, parameters, axios, payload

I have a webpack-dev-server config like

```
const path = require('path')
const CircularJSON = require('circular-json') //just to allow me to log circular references

module.exports = {
...
  devServer: {
    before(app) {
      app.all('/my/route', (req, res) => {
        console.log(CircularJSON.stringify(req))//req.query & req.params are empty {}
        
        // I wanna have access to sent payload from Axios here, eg:
        const result = {
          foo1: req.query.bar1,
          foo2: req.query.bar2
        }
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The equivalent axios call is like

```
axios.post('/my/route', {bar1: 'x', bar2: 'y'}).then(...) => {...})
```

I'm able to hit the route because I got the `console.log(CircularJSON.stringify(req))` output, but the `req.query` & `req.params` are empty. I suspect it is due to the fact that I was sending JSON data, but even with extra axios config `{headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }}` I couldn't get the data I wanna send.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to use 'body-parser'

```
const path = require('path')
const CircularJSON = require('circular-json') //just to allow me to log circular references
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

module.exports = {
...
  devServer: {
    before(app) {
      // use bodyParser for axios request
      app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
      app.use(bodyParser.json())

      app.all('/my/route', (req, res) => {
        console.log(CircularJSON.stringify(req))//req.query & req.params are empty {}
        
        // access them on req.body:
        const result = {
          foo1: req.body.bar1,
          foo2: req.body.bar2
        }
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
      });
    }
  }
}
```